# error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

For below code I am getting Assertion failed error as highlighted in title.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("Feed", frame)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Feed", frame)

Error - cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

In order to remove the path as suspect - video is same folder where I am code. I verified the path by replacing with image and it works fine.

I also verified I am able to open the video. Since I am on Mac - I tried with VLC and even converted the format to .mp4 for it support default quicktime player but still same error. If I just try to get image from video I do first frame - I have commented that code above.

If I try below set of code

```
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Feed", frame)
```

I no longer see above assertion failed error but the feed frame window opens and just hangs

I see it as common error when video or file is not available for being read by cv2.imshow(). I went through quite a few suggestions given around this in SO but somehow nothing worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried adding `cv2.waitKey(1)`  after `cv2.imshow()`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

after `cv2.imshow()`. I've encountered the same issue before, and adding that worked for me.